# How to setup a server using node.js and electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Node.JS and Electron, or server side scripting in general. I'm trying to create an electron app that has url patterns and can send and get data. But, i don't quite understand how nodeJS works exactly or even electron really, so i feel like i'm missing something. Sorry, if the question is too broad, I'm not really sure what to ask. Could any point me in the right direction to maybe some helpful resources or an explanation? Thanks

Comment: you want to build a website or a desctop app?

Comment: build a desktop app

Comment: electron quick start? http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electon is specifically not server side scripting. It uses web technology (chromium) and simply embeds it into your desktop app. It then allows you to write your application as javascript and html to run and render your desktop app. No server communication necessarily happens.

It, of course, has the ability to communicate back to a server though. That server would then be where your server side scripting would live, which may or may not be node.js.

Comment: So, if i wanted to have URL patterns that load different content based on the URL how would i go about doing that in electron? Could i simply use jquery and ajax? I should mention I'm using nodeJS and npm to run electron

Comment: The best way to think about it is as a single page application. Which basically means that your whole application lives as static files on the file system which is what electron loads up. From there you're doing your whole application as javascript and using ajax purely for api calls. It becomes apparent very quickly that you need a framework to help manage complexity. There are a couple good ones, I find angular to be easy to work with. Here is an example app I made that you may find useful: https://github.com/justinmchase/electron-tutorial

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks for the help I will check out your example app